# How to create a 3D matrix from values a two variable dependent relationship - Kinetic Energy

Tags: r, matrix, physics

I am trying to create a 3D matrix with x,y values relating to mass and velocity, and the z value relating to the energy between the two.

Using E=1/2*m*v^2

However, all posts and help pages I get that revolve around 3D matrix is a set and fixed rows and columns with associated Z values.

I am trying to use Plotly to graph a 3d surface essentially showing how mass, velocity relates to Energy.

Here are my initial 3 variables:

```
m <- seq(1,100,0.5)
v <- seq(1,10,0.05)
E <- .5 * m * v^2

mat <- matrix(data=E, nrow=m, ncol=v)
plot_ly(z=~mat) %>% add_surface()
```

However when I create a matrix out of this and try to plot it. It does not work.

I tried this as well and it plots, but not correctly:

```
df <- data.frame(m=m, v=v, E=E)
plot_ly(z=~data.matrix(df)) %>% add_surface()
```

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks

I am essentially looking for a matrix that looks something like this:

```
      [1,  ] [2,] # mass
[,0.5] E1   E2 # energy
[,1  ] E3   E4 # values
#velocity
```

The end goal of what I am looking for is going to be a surface 3D plot with x being mass, y being velocity, and Z being the calculated Energy. It should display a smooth surface trending up and both mass and velocity increases.

Answer (score 1):

Your code above is really computing a single line within the space of interest.  The first element of E corresponds to m=1 and v=1, the second element of E corresponds to m=1.5 and v=1.05, but you don't calculate anywhere E for m=1 and v=1.05 or the other combinations that the plot function needs to show a surface.

Instead you should use a function like `expand.grid` to compute a grid of m and v values to then calculate with, or possibly use the `outer` function to compute your matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Greg Snow mentioned but with code.

There are two ways this can be accomplished in plotly one is using a surface plot and the other one is using mesh3d:

mesh3d:

```
library(plotly)
```

make the grid of m and v values (I made it a bit sparser):

```
z <- expand.grid(m = seq(1,100,1),
                 v = seq(1,10,0.1))
```

calculate the energy

```
z$E <- with(z, .5 * m * v^2)
```

plot a mash3d

```
plot_ly(data = z, x = ~m, y = ~v, z = ~E, type = 'mesh3d')
```

[image]

the surface plot accepts a matrix of values so one needs to rearrange the grid:

```
library(tidyverse)
z <- expand.grid(m = seq(1,100,1),
                 v = seq(1,10,0.1))   

 z %>%
      mutate(E = .5 * m * v^2) %>%
      spread(key = v, value = E) %>%
      as.matrix() -> mat
```

Here you will need to do manual axis labeling since it will assume the grid is 1:n where n is the number of rows and columns

```
plot_ly() %>%
  add_surface(z = mat, x = unique(z$m), y = unique(z$v)) %>%
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "m"),
                      yaxis = list(title = "v"),
                      zaxis = list(title = "E")))
```

[image]